# How to make the toggle route path?

Tags: javascript, angular, toggle

I want to make the toggle of the router path with one tag `<a>`  how to implement it?

```
<a class="navbar-brand" *ngIf="!toggle" routerLink="login">Expensewatch</a>
<a class="navbar-brand" *ngIf="toggle" routerLink="report">Expensewatch</a>
```

Comment: it's unclear how your toggle will work, will it work onclick ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wish to implement these 2 lines in 1?

you could do something like this:

```
 <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="getCorretLink(toggle)">Expensewatch</a>
```

And in the component.js:

```
getCorretLink(toggle) { return toggle ? "report" : "login"; }
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: An alternative is to do it in the template: `[routerLink]="toggle ? 'report' : 'login'"`.